# How can I do onclick and save value to rails form hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table with these datas:

```
<td>10</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>20</td>
```

And a form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@posts) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.hidden_field :number, value: ??? %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Question:

How can I pass the data to the hidden_field value when I click on the table data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
$('#your_table_id td').on 'click' ->
  $('#posts_form').val($(this).val())
```

Where `$(this)` in this case is a clicked `td` element.